# Is it possible to position the Pinterest hover button

Tags: css, pinterest

I am using the Pinterest hover button widget for a client website.

https://developers.pinterest.com/on_hover_pin_it_buttons/

By default it appears at the top left of all images. It doesn't look like their script allows for positioning. Is it possible to override this with CSS?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? And can you provide an [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2xzxgvfw/

Comment: I have tried getting at the class of the link and a tags in general to see if I can use top/left positioning, looking at the source it puts the pin button in an iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I believe that it is. If you generate the code you will see that the pin it button is created as a span and then positioned with inline styles, I am guessing dynamically with each image.

In the example I looked at it had the class xc_pin, so I will use that for my example but bear in mind that the class you have may be different.

As I mentioned, the span is styled inline, so to overwrite it you will have to use !important, else the styles will be overwritten. Here is how your code could look:

```
xc_pin {
   left: 20px !important;
   top: 50px !important;
}
```

I hope that this helps!

**EDIT WITH WORKING JSFIDDLE**

After playing around with the css I managed to find a way to target it using the css sibling selector, here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xzxgvfw/19/

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried this in my websites stylesheet but it did not work. If you see the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2xzxgvfw/) the Pinterest widget is just a line of javascript so all the css is held on their server and an iframe is used to add the widget to the page.

Comment: I don't think it is an i-frame, when inspecting the element on the js-fiddle it seems to me that it just a styled a tag? That being said I found it very difficult to target it as it is being added dynamically. However it is definitely possible, and here i can change the style using just css: https://jsfiddle.net/2xzxgvfw/12/. I realise that you probably don't want to target all a's with an important class though as that will get messy really fast. I'm working on a way to add a class dynamically so it get styles when it appears.

Comment: Hi Harvey, your jsfiddle has got me the selector I needed in order to move the element. Many thanks! :)

Comment: This fiddle has a solution but it is based on a fixed image size, trying to align right with float and text align didn't cut it but if I figure it I will post it on here incase anyone else wants it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you generated the code but I think there should be somewhere a file called: **ppibfi_pinterest.css** in this file look for the line:

```
.pibfi_pinterest .xc_pin{}
```

there you should find something like: `top: 5px; margin-left: -1px;`
if you adjust this, you  should be able to modify the position of the pinterest icon